# Using LIKE to find an 'exact' match

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

Hi I need to add WHERE clause to my query.
The problem is that the number column contains value like:

```
(row 1) 1015/14,910/15
(row 2) 90/15,14/15
(row 3) 10/15, 900/15, 1000/15
(row 4) 1019/15, 1018/15
(row 5) null
```

....

It's number + year. In the column I can have more numbers or null value. Column type: string.

Now I need to find number **"10/15"** or other.

I tried using number LIKE '%10/15%' but result is:
(row1) 9**10/15**

AND (row3) 10/15...

so I can't use it.

When I try use WHERE nr = '10/15' I find only row with 1 number = 10/15.

So how do I find the rows only with my part of string but only full number? not part?

Comment: You should not be storing numbers or dates as strings.  You should not be storing lists in single columns.  You should fix your data model to have a proper junction table, or at least use built-in Postgres functionality such as arrays.  The right solution is to fix the data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a regular expression might work nicely here:

```
where num_text ~ '\D10/15\D|^10/15\D|\D10/15$|^10/15$'
```

the `\D` atom indicates any non-digit.

This is a little more obscure, but a `ts_vector` might actually work for you:

```
select *
from Your_Table
where
  to_tsvector(num_text) @@ '10/15'
```

The `ts_vector` approach as a scalability advantage to it -- if you are searching millions of rows, there are ways to make this really fast.  If you have 1,000 rows, then it hardly matters.

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest something that won't be too efficient if your tables has a lot of data in it, but you can do it with OR and checking all possibilities like this :

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE number LIKE '10/15,%'
      OR number like '%, 10/15,%' 
      OR number like '%, 10/15'
```

Just adjust it to the way you keep the data(with spaces or without since you posted both with spaces and without..)

Comment: Assuming the only 'distractor' is spaces, you could actually do it like this: `WHERE ',' + Replace(number, ' ', '') + ',' LIKE '%,' + '10/15' + ',%'` Not sure what will be faster, the replace or the three LIKE's in an OR.(string operations are always horribly slow)